# Simplifying an expression with both scalar quantities and matrices

Tags: matrix-equations

[I just obtained the expression in the image from integration. Now how do I further simplify this to expression x in terms of t. If possible, how can I graph the relationship between x and t (e.g., using a software/website).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPa6S.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Something is wrong with your equation in the nominator you add a metric to a complex number?

Comment: That is the issue, I employed the Duhamel's principle to integrate a differential then got this expression

Comment: That is indeed the issue. You clearly misapplied Duhamel's principle and ended up with a nonsensical expression. You need to back up and figure out your mistake. At the very least, you were using notation you didn't understand.